# How to show a SQL Server row as a list of result in an e-mail in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

Using ASP.NET MVC and SQL Server via stored procedures, I am trying to send an e-mail to a user.

The e-mail should contain the info of an order which the user has confirmed. This info is retrieved from the database.

Using a SQL query, I have succeeded only to show the first paramater of the query (take a look please at the picture to see the contents of the e-mail).

Controller:

```
  private void connection()
  {
        string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DeliveryCon"].ToString();
        con = new SqlConnection(constring);
  }

  public JsonResult SendMailToUser()
  {
      connection();
      con.Open();

      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Email from Bestellung where BestellungId=(Select MAX(BestellungId) From Bestellung)", con);

      SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("select First_Name, Last_Name, Adresse, Email, Phone, Date, Time, Nbre_P, Items from Bestellung where BestellungId=(Select MAX(BestellungId) From Bestellung)", con);

      string em = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
      string sub = command2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

      con.Close();

      bool result = false;

      result = SendEmail(em, "Delivery : Your Order", sub);
      return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public bool SendEmail(string toEmail, string subject, string emailBody)
{
        try
        {
            string senderEmail = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderEmail"].ToString();
            string senderPassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderPassword"].ToString();

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Timeout = 100000;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderEmail, senderPassword);
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(senderEmail, toEmail, subject, emailBody);

            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
            client.Send(mailMessage);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

View:

```
<input type="submit" value="Confirm" style="margin-left:-270px;" onclick="SendEmail()">
<script>
    var SendEmail = function () {

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Bestellung/SendMailToUser",


            success: function (data) {
                alert ("Success")

            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

The contents of the e-mail:

[image]

**Ganfoud** represent here the **First_Name** which is the first parameter in the query

```
SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("select First_Name
```

**EDIT :**

```
 SqlDataReader reader = command2.ExecuteReader();
 List<object[]> dataList = new List<object[]>();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                object[] tempRow = new object[reader.FieldCount];
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    tempRow[i] = reader[i];
                }
                dataList.Add(tempRow);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
        }
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: Use `SqlDataReader` with `ExecuteReader` to fetch results and use `GetString` with column index to get column values.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto that's what I am planning to do but the problem that I want to show a hole list in the Email and not a column

Comment: `string sub = DataReader.GetString(3)` => is this what you want? If selected recipients are more than one, consider using `List<string>.Add()` and then use `foreach` loop to execute `SendEmail` from that list.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto the question is what should I write instead of "sub" here : result = SendEmail(em, "Delivery : Your Order", sub);

Comment: The third argument of `SendMail` is `string emailBody`, right? If you want to include other text than single recipient name, use a list of recipients and concatenate them with message body in certain part like mail merge does. What I know the passed value must have same type as the argument has.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto: yes, sub is the emailbody.
can you please see the EDIT that I have made and try to help how can I the list create

Answer (score 2):

You execute your query using `ExecuteScalar`. [According to the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar):

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

That explains why your email only contains the first name.

If you need to access the different columns, use [`ExecuteReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx) and fetch the data on the returned `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: @Riokmji thanks for the answer, ok I understand and I tried that before but the problem how to fetch data, can you please explain more your suggestion

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader for more information.